# reusing queries in jmeter

Tags: database, jmeter

I am using Jmeter to test API's. I am often using queries to access the DB (JCDB connection)

So far so good. However as i am using more and more queries it seems i am copying data.

For instance:

Thread 1:
HTTP request 1
Query A
Query B
Query C

Thead 2:
HTTP request 2
Query D
Query A

Thead 3:
HTTP request 3
Query A
Query C

As you can see. I have the same query duplicate it often. Not only on 1 jmx file but i have a lot of jmx files where i use Query API

So i am looking for a way to have to write query A once. I would think to create a new jmx file and just include the jmx file and call to that. Is this a good way to appraoch this? Also how do i call Query A from any thread? I would need to pass (and return) parameters.

Help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you read this? [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're looking for the [Module Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Module_Controller), you can define a "module" per query

[image]

and build your test using the "modules" instead of copying and pasting the real JDBC Request samplers

[image]

If you're going to store the "modules" as external .jmx files consider using [Test Fragments](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#test_fragments)